# Using Strongly typed DataSet in VB.Net Project

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, strongly-typed-dataset

Is using strongly typed dataset is good.

Currently I am working on a project developed using VB.Net in Visual Studio 2010.

Previously they were using Sql queries directly into SqlCommand of System.Data.SqlClient, but then after i shifted everything to Strongly Typed DataSet and started using TableAdapters every where..

Now i just wanna ask that is this way is good for a project...
Or Should i shift back to old ones using Just SqlCommands

Or Is there any way to make Sql DataBase in a good way because its an ERP and most of the code is for Data Access..

Answer (score 1):

We use strongly typed datasets all the time now.

After shifting to this behaviour it felt really bad to have SQL-querys in code instead of having it done by the table adapter. But there is a bit overhead with datasets so I guess booth ways are good for different solutions.

Its really nice to have intellisence on all fieldnames and if you change a tableadapter so it returns something different you get design-time errors everywhere where you need to change the code to reflect the change, instead of finding out runtime when the customer is running the program.

There are so many win win-things with strongly typed datasets so I'll never go back.

Comment: but when you see the code file of strongly data type it has nearly 50,000 lines of code for just 20 tableadapters.. is this good and some one told me that strongly typed data set consumes long time for execution because it type cast every thing

Comment: For me, this overhead is nothing against the features I get using it. I have webservice-projects with 40-50 datasets in it, handling all data between server and clients without having any performance-problems. But everything is about what need you have. Of course there are cases where datasets is not the solution. But If you dont use datasets because of the *overhead*, maybe something else is the problem...

Comment: I would never recommend worrying about performance before performance is actually a problem.  You could spend 6 months writing code that executes in a tick instead of a millisecond but would the user actually notice any difference?  Moral of the story - if its better practice and easier to maintain without a monstrous overhead do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Table adapters  .... make a lot of mess with bigger databases, also updating the table structure also causes confusion.
I would recommend to use some auto code generators for the CRUD Operations.
To me your old pattern looks better than switching altogether to table adapters and strongly typed datasets.

Comment: Updating table structures when having sql-querys sprinkled everywhere in the sourcecode is a bigger pain. Its about discipline. Change the table, open DS and change tableadapter, then fix the places that is affected (you see all in the error window). 

The old way: Change table, go to sourcecode and try to find all querys that are affected, miss some, then try find all places where fields are used, miss some. Find out when program is running, worst case the customer find it, not you. Sometime stupid programmers are using row.fields(0) instead of field name, really fun to search for those..

Answer (score 0):

If you ever want to move your data across the wire to other platforms (silverlight, web services, wcf services, etc), then using any kind of dataset will box you into a corner.

The way that we have resolved this is to have classes whose list of properties match the database exactly. To move the data in and out of the database, we use reflection to either match stored procedure parameters or generate dynamic SQL statements, depending on the circumstance and platform.

When a database table is changed, the developer making the change is also responsible for updating the class structure and vice-versa.

In order to reduce the amount of hand-coding required, we use the code generation capabilities of CodeSmith to generate classes from the database and create the basic implementations of our standard add/update stored procedures that require field enumeration.

As an added benefit, this approach removes the tight link between the database and business object structure. We are able to use our same data access code and business object classes against SQL Server, Oracle, Sqlite, and SqlServerCE databases. This code is used to create applications in Windows, PocketPC, Web, iPad, and Android apps; all of the mobile apps use local databases specific to the platform, but using the common data access code.

It is a bit more work to setup initially, but it will pay significant dividends in the long run.